# Select orderBy & limit slow for a table with 3,000,000 rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, indexing

I need help for a query that takes too much time to retrieve datas.

```
SELECT DISTINCT dataSet.professionalSid
FROM dataSet dataSet
INNER JOIN dataProfessional dataPro ON dataSet.sId=dataPro.dataSetSid
LEFT OUTER JOIN dataProfessional dataPro2  ON dataSet.sId=dataPro2.dataSetSid
AND (dataPro2.itemDefinitionId='PRO_NOM_EXERCICE'
     AND dataPro2.dataSetDefinitionId='DIRECTORY_PROFESSIONAL_RPPS')
WHERE dataSet.archive=0
  AND dataPro.dataSetDefinitionId='DIRECTORY_PROFESSIONAL_RPPS'
  AND (dataPro.itemDefinitionId IN ('PRO_PRENOM_EXERCICE'))
  AND MATCH(dataSet.searchIndex) AGAINST('+*p* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)>=1
ORDER BY dataPro2.stringValue DESC LIMIT 10
```

The table dataProfessional contains about 3.7m rows and dataSet about 820,000 rows, others tables are only table def containing only 5-10 rows.

This query return about 28k rows but I limit it to 10.

Index :

Table dataSet

```
+---------+------------+-----------------------------+--------------+--------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+
|  Table  | Non_unique |          Key_name           | Seq_in_index |       Column_name        | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type |
+---------+------------+-----------------------------+--------------+--------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+
| dataSet |          0 | PRIMARY                     |            1 | sId                      | A         |      846564 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| dataSet |          0 | sId                         |            1 | sId                      | A         |      846564 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| dataSet |          1 | FK_dataSetDefinitionDataSet |            1 | dataSetDefinitionId      | A         |          70 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| dataSet |          1 | FK_dataSetDefinitionDataSet |            2 | dataSetDefinitionVersion | A         |          76 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| dataSet |          1 | FK_dataSetPatient           |            1 | patientSid               | A         |        2263 | NULL     | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |
| dataSet |          1 | FK_dataSetProfessional      |            1 | professionalSid          | A         |      846564 | NULL     | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |
| dataSet |          1 | FK_overrideDataSet          |            1 | overrideDataSetSid       | A         |           2 | NULL     | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |
| dataSet |          1 | FullText                    |            1 | searchIndex              | NULL      |      846564 | NULL     | NULL   | YES  | FULLTEXT   |
+---------+------------+-----------------------------+--------------+--------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+
```

Table dataProfessional

```
+------------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+--------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+
|      Table       | Non_unique |           Key_name            | Seq_in_index |       Column_name        | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type |
+------------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+--------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+
| dataProfessional |          0 | PRIMARY                       |            1 | sId                      | A         |     3636911 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| dataProfessional |          0 | sId                           |            1 | sId                      | A         |     3636911 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| dataProfessional |          1 | FK_dataSetDataPro             |            1 | dataSetSid               | A         |     1818455 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| dataProfessional |          1 | FK_itemDefinitionDataPro      |            1 | itemDefinitionVersion    | A         |           2 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| dataProfessional |          1 | FK_itemDefinitionDataPro      |            2 | itemDefinitionId         | A         |        8172 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| dataProfessional |          1 | FK_dataProfessionalDataSetDef |            1 | dataSetDefinitionId      | A         |         952 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| dataProfessional |          1 | FK_dataProfessionalDataSetDef |            2 | dataSetDefinitionVersion | A         |         952 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| dataProfessional |          1 | stringValue                   |            1 | stringValue              | A         |      909227 | 10       | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |
+------------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+--------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+
```

This is the explain of the query:

```
+-----+-------------+----------+----------+---------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+----------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  id | select_type |  table   |   type   |                   possible_keys                   |        key        | key_len |            ref             | rows |                    Extra                     |
+-----+-------------+----------+----------+---------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+----------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|   1 | SIMPLE      | dataSet  | fulltext | PRIMARY   sId   FullText                          | FullText          |       0 |                            |    1 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|   1 | SIMPLE      | dataPro  | ref      | FK_dataSetDataPro   FK_dataProfessionalDataSetDef | FK_dataSetDataPro |       8 | cloud_dev_eret.dataSet.sId |    2 | Using where; Distinct                        |
|   1 | SIMPLE      | dataPro2 | ref      | FK_dataSetDataPro   FK_dataProfessionalDataSetDef | FK_dataSetDataPro |       8 | cloud_dev_eret.dataSet.sId |    2 | Using where; Distinct                        |
+-----+-------------+----------+----------+---------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+----------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Have you an idea where I can look? 
Tell me if you need more elements

Thanks

Comment: does dataPro2.stringValue has a index?

Comment: yes it does, i used this command 'ALTER TABLE `dataProfessional` ADD INDEX `stringValue` (`stringValue`(10));'.

Comment: You say the table has 3 million rows.  But your query joins multiple tables. So which one has 3 million, what are the sizes of the other ones? Also, how many rows are returned by your query?  And when you run the query without an `order by`, do you actually fetch *all* the rows, or are you only timing the query based on when you get the first few rows back?

Comment: I've edited and put more elements, thank you for your help

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate but the answer is still valid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38526528/simple-query-very-slow-due-to-order-by/38526640#38526640

Comment: Try an index on `dataProfessional(itemDefinitionId, dataSetDefinitionId)`

Answer (score 1):

I think that the `EXPLAIN` output rather-bluntly tells you all that you need to know.

I see indexes being used for `JOINs`, but *only* for joins. I do not see any to help important clauses such as `dataPro2.itemDefinitionId='PRO_NOM_EXERCICE'`. I also see a "fullText" search, which can be crippling.

Neither do I see an index being used for *"dataSet*sid" in support of `ON dataSet.sId=dataPro2.dataSetSid`.

In short, the `EXPLAIN` output probably tells all: you're basically doing a brute-force search, and the number of candidate rows might be truly enormous. *(e.g.* if either `sId/dataSetSid` field is not-unique resulting in a [partial] Cartesian Product situation.)

Answer (score 1):

"This query return about 28k rows but I limit it to 10." -- Because of the way the query is structured (`FULLTEXT`, `LEFT`, `ORDER BY`, etc), it will have to find the 28K rows before getting to the `ORDER BY & LIMIT`.  The only way to avoid speed up the query is to to shrink the 28K and/or speed up individual pieces.

Notice that the `EXPLAIN` says that it starts with the `FULLTEXT` index, ignoring the other indexes.  *Usually* this is the 'right' thing to do.  But not with `AGAINST('+*p* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` -- that is virtually useless.  You are essentially looking for any `searchIndex` with a `p` in it?  That will be much of the table.  But it is going to the extra effort of using an index.

This would be faster, but still not fast:  `searchIndex LIKE '%p%'`

Test what I said by timing these and seeing if they get the same counts:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*)
    FROM dataSet
    WHERE MATCH(dataSet.searchIndex) AGAINST('+*p* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)>=1;
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*)
    FROM dataSet
    WHERE searchIndex LIKE '%p%';
```

The `JOIN` to `dataPro` seems to be useless; what is its purpose?

`dataProfessional` needs `INDEX(itemDefinitionId, dataSetDefinitionId, dataSetSid)` in any order.

Could the `LEFT JOIN` be simply `JOIN`?

Is the `*p*` generated by the user?  Consider disallowing such.  Consider turning it into the `%p%` I suggested.  Consider other options to avoid such a slow query.